# Spring: Is using EntitiyManager in a @Component+@Transactional class thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, entitymanager

I am using JPA (Hibernate) in a Spring project and asking myself if my class 'BooksHandler' (which is a DAO) is thread safe ?

Code for my App Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    emf.setPackagesToScan("jpa.models");
    JpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    emf.setJpaProperties(getProperties());
    return emf;
}

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dtSrc = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dtSrc.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dtSrc.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa_example");
    dtSrc.setUsername("dbuser1");
    dtSrc.setPassword("dbuser1");
    return dtSrc;
}
private Properties getProperties() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    return p;
}

//auto transaction management
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    manager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return manager;
}

//auto exception management
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor getPostProcessor() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
}
```

DAO class:

```
@Component 
@Transactional 
public class BooksHandler {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public Book createBook(String title, String isbn, int year) {
    Book b = new Book();
    b.setIsbn(isbn);b.setTitle(title);b.setYear(year);
    em.persist(b);
    System.out.println("book created: "+b.getId());
    return b;
}

public Book getBook(int id) {
    return em.find(Book.class, id);
}
//other CRUD methods
}
```

The method of BooksHandler will be used by multiple threads and I know that EntityManager itself is NOT thread-safe. But an online course I am attending does it this way. Maybe there is some behind the scene magic by spring to make it thread safe ?

Comment: Yes, it is thread-safe. Spring injects a proxy that delegates to the EM associated to the current transaction/thread. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-jpa-dao. It's all explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But in the documentation they are using EntityManagerFactory (thread-safe) to get an EntityManager do operation and then close it and the end of the CRUD method. In my Example I am using EntityManager directly and not from factory. Is it still thread-safe ?

Comment: Read more than the first sentence. The section I linked to literally says: "The injected JPA EntityManager behaves like an EntityManager fetched from an application server’s JNDI environment, as defined by the JPA specification. It delegates all calls to the current transactional EntityManager, if any. Otherwise, it falls back to a newly created EntityManager per operation, **in effect making its usage thread-safe**. (emphasis mine). And the 4th example snippet in that section shows the usage of an injected EM.

Comment: Right, Thanks !

Comment: Post your text as answer, it solved my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is thread-safe. Spring injects a proxy that delegates to the EM associated to the current transaction/thread. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-jpa-dao), which says:

> The injected JPA EntityManager behaves like an EntityManager fetched from an application server’s JNDI environment, as defined by the JPA specification. It delegates all calls to the current transactional EntityManager, if any. Otherwise, it falls back to a newly created EntityManager per operation, **in effect making its usage thread-safe**.

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

If by thread safe, you mean that you won't have any errors of **Dirty Read**, **Non Repeatable Read** or **Phantom Read**. No, that depends wholly on your transaction isolation level, which is configure in your Hibernate properties or in each `@Transactional` annotation.

Otherwise, it doesn't really matter much if two different sessions or thread (if you are using `@Async`), can access the same class methods at the same time, since in the end, it will purely depend on your isolation level. This [blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) gives a good idea about when to use which isolation level.